# how to fix a problem with BaleBot in Python host

Tags: python, bots, bale-messenger, balebot

I write a simple BaleBot and test it successfully on my PC.
I uploaded it in free python host (pythoneverywhere.com) and set a python 3.6 virtual environment with BaleBot package but after run it in Bash console i got an error in making instance of updater.bot:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "myappname/test_bot1.py",
>   line 13, in 
>       bot = updater.bot AttributeError: 'Updater' object has no attribute 'bot'

I guess this problem is related to importing balebot packages but I can't find the main reason.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace

```
updater = Updater(token=Config.bot_token, loop=asyncio.get_event_loop())
bot=updater.bot
```

with :

```
updater = Updater(token=Config.bot_token, loop=asyncio.get_event_loop())
bot = updater.dispatcher.bot
```

It's because and update in balebot package. Actually in old version bot was an attribute of Updater but now it's not.

Comment: That problem is fixed, but a new error is raised:

network.py:112  WARNING:
"network connection disconnected."
2018-09-28 19:04:04,841  network.py:36  ERROR:
"connect error: Cannot connect to host api.bale.ai:443 ssl:True [Connect call failed ('185.13.231.73', 443)]"
Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
.

Comment: After  upgrading Balebot package  on my PC and changing the code i face to a new problem. Bot run without error and connect to server but it  does nothing

Comment: maybe it’s because server disconnecting and it’s ok now, if it occurred again you would need to send logs to me.

Comment: too long log, how can i send log through the site?

Comment: @Ehsanbarkhordar is my nick name in bale.

Comment: please check your Bale account